# php mssql_connect not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Here's the code that I am using.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$myServer = "ip-address:1334/SQLEXPRESS";
$myUser = "username";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "dbname";

$link = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass);
if ( !$link ) {
  if ( function_exists('error_get_last') ) {
     var_dump(error_get_last());
           }
  die('connection failed');
   }
  ?>
```

Now this code is running on a linux machine and the server is on a windows server. The IP is correct as well as username, password I created a new pair inside SQLEXPRESS. However, I still get a connection issue.

```
 Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server
```

the port 1334 is opened by our windows server and SQL server is listening to both 1334 and 1433. THey wont open default port for security reasons. They have double checked the settings but I still cannot connect.

What should be the next action for me.

Kind regards

Khuram

Comment: what is the ip-address in your $myServer?

Comment: @G molvi its a valid ip address of our windows server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the windows SQL server have a firewall restriction which is restricting to access from outside of the server.

Comment: they say that they have allowed outside access on port 1334 but I cant connect through telnet either.

Answer (score 2):

For connecting Linux + Apache + SQLEXPRESS 2005 take care about it:

- Don´t use the standard MS-SQL port (1433), use the MS-SQL dynamic port under SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Express Protocols -> TCP/IP properties -> IP Adresses -> IPAll
- You can do a direct connection (without FreeTDS) using the following statemt:

  $db=mssql_connect('192.168.xxx.xxx:1541','usrxxxx','pwdxxxx');

-You can use FreeTDS configuring the freetds.conf file as follow:

```
  [connect2k5]
  host = 192.168.xxx.xxx
  port = 1541
  tds version = 8.0
```

With the following PHP statement:

```
  $db=mssql_connect('connect2k5','usrxxxx','pwdxxxx');
```

I have got it from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

You can also try http://www.akamarketing.com/blog/99-php-sql-server-connection-problems-mssql_connect-functionmssql-connect-unable-to-connect-to-server.html

Comment: Hi Sazzad, I checked Dynamic port and tried to connect to it but I could not do it through php or telnet. Could it be firewall. The server has mcafee installed and I dont see any port blocking rules in there.

Comment: Try by  disabling all the firewall rules along with the antivirus.
What is the version of your server?
And is the server in the local area network or in a public IP?

Answer (score 1):

The port may not be open. You should be able to connect via telnet to port 1334 or 1433. You won't get any text back, but it will connect.